# how to call a toggle function

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code :

```
$("#First").toggle(function() {
 $('#Second').load('http://www.astralinternet.com/smtp_provider.php', function() {});
  ... stuff ...
 }, function() {
   hide stuff...
   etc...
 });
```

This is used with div similar to those  :

```
<div id="First" style="
    position:aboslute;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
"></div>
<div id="Second" style="
    position:aboslute;
    height:380px;
    width:380px;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
"></div>
```

Now, I would like the toggle to be trigger by both #first and #Second

I've tried calling the toggle this way:

```
 $("#first, #Second").toggle(function() { ...
```

it gives funny result, since both div act as if they have their own toggle event.

I've tried adding :

```
 $("#Second").click(function() { $("#Firsrt").toggle() });
```

And that only added a "display" toggle on my First div.

Thank for the input.

Comment: Your script is off the wall...and your question is quite hard to understand...

Comment: You have multiple character issues in your examples (I hope they're examples)

Comment: It a quick written example, the original code was a little big for the post, but if needed, I may place it....

Comment: Is ti possible to "Bind" both ID with the toggle event?

Comment: I have a minor suggestion: cache your ajax result so you don't need to send a request every time it is toggled. Also your design for toggling sounds a bit confusing. :(

Comment: This form of `toggle` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9. See http://forum.jquery.com/topic/beginner-function-toggle-deprecated-what-to-use-instead for workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my issue. I've replace the tottle and used a switch case :

```
var iteration = 1;
$('.SMTP_SHOW, .SMTP_CONTENT').click(function(){
switch ( iteration) {
    case 1:
               Stuff...
               break;
            case 2:
               Stuff...
               break;               
    }
iteration++;
if (iteration>2) iteration=1
})
```

This way both ID are link to the same trigger (or switch in this case...)